# what's the password when Transferring files with gcloud compute scp？

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I wanted to Transferring files with gcloud compute scp (https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-lamp), after running VM, connect SSH key, I input（ gcloud compute scp [local file path]  root@lamp-2:/home/ ）on cloud shell  , the system prompt me to inter root@compute.194334494129028111's password, what does that mean?

Comment: does `gcloud auth list` show the google account with access to that instance?

Comment: yes, it shows  Credentialed Account and the ACCOUNT is my gmail

Comment: does `~/.ssh/google_compute_engine` exist on your local machine? You could also try `--force-key-file-overwrite` to see if it will regenerate a key for you. (just some suggestions from browsing the docs at https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp)

Comment: from cloud shell I can see ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine, but what do you mean 'local machine'? my mac computer? you mean I should put google_compute_engine on my own mac?

Comment: by local machine I mean wherever the file you are trying to copy over exists

Comment: They are working on Cloud Shell, not on their local mac.

Comment: This question is more suited to Serverfault where it should be asked. Stackoverflow is generally for developers and Serverfault is aimed at system and network administrators).

Answer (score 0):

The correct command from the tutorial is:

`gcloud compute copy-files [LOCAL_FILE_PATH] lamp-tutorial:/somepath`

Why are you specifying a different user (root) for the target? You can always scp the files to a different users, then ssh into the machine and copy the files to another user's directory (assuming you have permission for the other user).

Generally, when scp asks for a password, it didn't find a matching ssh key. Different users on the target machine would have different ssh keys. What do you mean by "connect SSH key"? Did you connect to the vm as described in the tutorial or did you set up ssh access with `ssh-keygen` from Cloud Shell to the VM?

Comment: maybe my problem is that I shouldn't transfer mac file to remote instance. I solve my problem by transfer mac file to google storage bucket, then transfer bucket to remote  instance. thanks for your answering.